# Company is indifferent to my immigration issues - should I contact the CEO?

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom

I am working for a company for the last 3 years, they sponsored me on Tier 2 General.

My UK visa will expire in July of this year, the company was supposed to renew their COS allocations in January but they still haven't done it.

Here are the reasons I have been told for this:

- HR was too busy, they applied in March but it was rejected for reasons not known to me
- Their immigration lawyer was too busy

In the same period as above they were able to get another newly-hired (less than one year) employee restricted COS for their visa (This process is far tougher than what they need to do for me).

I re-informed my manager about my concerns but nothing much has changed.

HR deceived me by saying that they received COS allocations in March but later on we found out that their request was rejected by Home Office.

This is a small company and I am desperate to get my visa extended otherwise my residence clock will be reset and I won't be able to come back for a year.

I tried explaining my problems to my manager and HR but they just don't seem to be taking matter as seriously as they ought to.

**Summary**

- HR doesn't seem to be understanding the urgency of the situation
- My manager doesn't let me talk to HR about immigration. He wants me to go through him for unknown reasons

Maybe there is something else going on which I am not sure about?

I believe I am a productive part of my team but you never know what is going on in other people's hearts.

**Questions**

- I have very little time and I am desperate to get my visa extended. Should I involve company's CEO as it's a small company of less then 50 people. If yes, then what should I say?
- I have been told by the manager that if I speak to the CEO and if he gets angry over the matter, I might get fired (I am not sure how true this is).

**Not so related concerns**

- In worst case scenario if I couldn't extend my visa, I will have very little time to tell my landlord about leaving the house I rented.
- Similarly getting vaccination for my family including less than a year old son.

and other travel related issues etc.

Comment: How well do you know the CEO, and how well does he know you? Is escalating things to him a usual event? Is this the sort of thing he'd get involved in? Is there a manager between your manager and the CEO you could escalate to first? And whilst it shouldn't stop you escalating if you need to, have you chased your manager hard enough to get him to chase HR? Talk to him daily, don't accept excuses for no progress ("I haven't had time" "Oh, can you call them now?" etc.), offer to help chase people in HR if he can put you in touch, and so on.

Comment: If you're considering ignoring your manager's requests, I would be going around him to speak directly to HR, not to the CEO.

Comment: "for unknown reasons" - because you haven't asked? or because he won't answer you when do ask? There are a few other red flags here - either with you manager, or your organisation

Comment: Thanks for useful advises, i will try to speak to hr first now

Comment: @lowEQ I know this thread is a little bit old, but shouldn’t you be able to apply for a PR after working 33 month in UK?

Answer (score 3):

You can hope for a miracle if the CEO knows and likes you personally, and it sounds like you can't make things worse so you might as well try, but the CEO would generally let lower management decide whether you were worth the trouble. Delegation is why multiple layers of management exist, after all.

Make plans assuming you will lose this appeal.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your CEO if he has time to discuss some Problems that you could not solve with your Manager.

You can't drop the bom on him. Ask him if he has time for your Problems related to x. Seeing as you are a relatively small Company he might even know what you are talking about from the start.

Honestly you should have started this process sooner and or pushed more.
I am assuming that if you lose your visa that you AND your familiy have to leave. I would not like it to have my 1 year old on a plane (Seeing as you are likely not european).